# Mocking pinia store with vitest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, pinia, vitest

I'm trying to mock a pinia store, but the `vi.mock` doesn't work

```
import { it, describe, expect, vi, beforeEach } from 'vitest';
import { shallowMount, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { setActivePinia, createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

import AdsView from '@/views/AdsView.vue'


vi.mock('vue-router')
vi.mock('@/stores/style', () => ({
  useStyleStore: () => ({
    darkMode: true,
  }),
}));

describe('AdsView', () => {
  (useRoute as any).mockReturnValue({
    query: {
    },
  })

  beforeEach(() => {
    // creates a fresh pinia and make it active so it's automatically picked
    // up by any useStore() call without having to pass it to it:
    // `useStore(pinia)`
    // const pinia = createPinia().use(somePlugin)
    // app.use(pinia)
    // setActivePinia(pinia)
    // setActivePinia(createPinia())
  })

  it('renders the correct markup', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(AdsView)
    expect(wrapper.html()).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('fetches ads on mount', async () => {
    const fetchAdsMock = vi.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data: [{ id: 1, title: 'Ad 1' }, { id: 2, title: 'Ad 2' }] });
    const wrapper = mount(AdsView, {
      mocks: {
        $http: {
          get: fetchAdsMock,
        },
      },
      global: {
        plugins: [createTestingPinia({createSpy: vi.fn})],
      },
    });

    // Wait for the component to render
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    // Assert that the ads were fetched and rendered
    expect(fetchAdsMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(wrapper.find('.ad')).toHaveLength(2);
  });
})
```

results in

```
 FAIL  views/AdsView.spec.ts > AdsView > fetches ads on mount
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'darkMode')
 ❯ Proxy._sfc_render layouts/Layout.vue:84:38
     83|   <div
     84|     :class="{
     85|       dark: styleStore.darkMode,
```

AdsView.vue

```
<template>
  <Layout>
    ...
    <div v-for="item in ads" :key="item.id"
    ....
</template>
<script setup>

...

const fetchAds = async () => {
   const response = await apiClient.get("/ad", { params: params })
...

onMounted(async () => {
  params.status = route.query.status || "approved"
  params.filter = route.query.filter || ""
  await fetchAds()
})
</script>
```

I tried to modify the path, but no dice. Any tips?

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/2092#discussioncomment-5534143

Comment: Why do you want to mock rather than using pinia store itself like you were doing it (the commented code in the `beforeeach` ) ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how my team made it work, hopefully it will work for other people. I'm going to use an inexistent store named `some` just for demonstration.

```
import { expect, vi, it, describe } from "vitest";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import { useSomeStore } from "./some";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";

// let's mock vue router first
vi.mock("vue-router", () => {
    return { useRoute: vi.fn().mockReturnValue({ params: { someParameter: "some_string" } }) };
});

it("mocks useRoute", () => {
    expect(useRoute().params.someParameter).toEqual("some_string");
});

describe("Block of tests", () => {
    // let's now mock the store
    const mockSomeStore = useSomeStore(createPinia());

    // modify the state of the store like so:
    mockSomeStore.$state.exampleBoo = false;

    it("should be false", () => {
        expect(mockSomeStore.exampleBoo).toBe(false);
    });
});
```